# Issues with the return channel of an external package function

Tags: go, return-value, channel

This code below is part of a job that I am doing.
The "main" function is executed, but without printing the map returned by the called function, which is found in another package.
I did tests on this last function, and it does generate the return.
I can't find my mistakes.

```
func main() {
    // This is part of the code
    // The channel "dataEntry" and "channelTJD", and the "waitgroup", was created previously. There are return channels of other functions.

    PositionPlsChan := make(chan map[float64]map[int]map[int][]float64, 1)

    // Code to verify that the channel works
    if PositionPlsChan == nil {
        fmt.Println("\nPositionPlsChan is NIL")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("\nPositionPlsChan is NOT nil") // Print this option when run the code
    }

    func() {
        go func() {
            // Call the function of the other package
            plnts.PlntsUT(dataEntry, channelTJD, &espera, PositionPlsChan)
            }()
        
        for {
            // Code to verify that the channel works
            select {
            case receives, ok := <-PositionPlsChan:
                if ok {
                    fmt.Println("receives", receives) // It should print the value contained in the channel
                } else {
                    fmt.Println("Channel cerrado")
                }
            default:
                println("There is not value in channel. Waiting.") // but print this option
            }
        }       
    }()
}
```

## OTHER PACKAGE

This code works based on the checks I did

```
package plnts

func PlntsUT(

    dataEntryChan chan entradadatos.DataEntry, 
    channelTJD chan float64, 
    wg *sync.WaitGroup, 
    ChannelReturn chan map[float64]map[int]map[int][]float64,
) {
    dataEntry := <-dataEntryChan // Receive the channel
    tjd := <-channelTJD // Receive the channel
    
    // Create a map from maps
    var plntsMap = map[float64]map[int]map[int][]float64{}
 
   //Initialize the map of maps
    plntsMap[tjd] = map[int]map[int][]float64{}
    
    for _, bodieValue := range dataEntry.Plnts { // Plnts is []int
        // Channel to send as argument
        var sendData = make(chan receivesData, 1)
        defer close(sendData) 

        //Channel to send and receive the return of the function to call
        var receivesPlsChan = make(chan []float64, 1)
        defer close(receivesPlsChan) 

        // Initialize map of maps
        plntsMap[tjd][bodieValue] = map[int][]float64{}
        
        for _, iflagValue := range dataEntry.Sistem { // Sistema is []int                           
            variableStruct := receivesData{
                tjd:   tjd,
                bodie: bodieValue,
                iflag: iflagValue,              
            }
            
            sendData <- variableStruct
            
            go func() {
                    // Call another function in the same package
                calcUnPlntUT(sendData, receivesPlsChan)
            }()

            //Send the channel value to the map
            plntsMap[tjd][bodieValue][iflagValue] = <-receivesPlsChan           
        }
    }

    // Initialize the map
    ChannelReturn = make(chan map[float64]map[int]map[int][]float64, 1)

    if ChannelReturn == nil {
        fmt.Println("channelReturn is NIL")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("channelReturn is NIL") // Print this option
    }
    
    ChannelReturn <- plntsMap // The channel received the map value
    
    // Code to verify that the channel works
    // This portion of code will be commented (//),
    // so that it is not executed, after verifying 
    // that the channel receives the value.

    // select {
    // case _, ok := <-ChannelReturn:
    //      if ok {
    //          fmt.Println("Value in channel") // Print this option
    //      } else {
    //          fmt.Println("Channel Closed")
    //      }
    //      default:
    
    println("No value in channel")
    }

    // Code to verify that the map has value
    fmt.Println("\n map of maps", plntsMap) // Print the map of maps
}
```

Output:

`````
PS C:\Go-Project\src\Ast> go run main.go
Main 1. It receives the channel dataEntry and is sent as a parameter to PlntsUT()

Main 2. channelTJD:  2.4400405e+06 

Main 3. PositionPlsChan was created. It is not nil

Main 4. Into goroutine. PlntsUT() is called. Sent parameters: dataEntry, channelTJD, & wait, PositionPlsChan.

               4.1 PlntsUT() - Start function
               4.2 PlntsUT() - The map was sent to the return channel
               4.3 PlntsUT() - Print map just before returning function: map[2.4400405e+06:map[0:map[33026:[101.12041750507854 -0.001946848541607366 1.0167564776934892 0.9653730337078059 0.0017513658174335596 -4.0388756783471536e-05]] 1:map[33026:[183.9503825565266 0.06704869143353376 0.0025344011723499632 14.97294331983312 -0.403467984791267 0.00017180324011524528]] 2:map[33026:[83.55721667001407 -4.271338209324602 0.6859570219539189 0.23997190595537177 0.11856886765748698 0.016097833472894507]]]]

Main 5. PlntsUT() was called

Main 6. Into select, PositionPlsChan pass its value
to the variable receives and checks it. This is the select code:

            for {
                 select {
                         case receives, ok := <-PositionPlsChan:
                                 if ok {
                                         fmt.Println("\nMain 7. Chek: ok== true: receives =", receives)
                                 } else {
                                         fmt.Println("\nMain 7. Chek: ok!= true: The variable receives is not printed:")
                                 }
                         default:
                                 fmt.Println("Main 7. Chek (select). Default option. There is no value in the channel. Waiting")
                                                                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)

                                                        }

Main 7. Chek (select). Default option. There is no value in the channel. Waiting
Main 7. Chek (select). Default option. There is no value in the channel. Waiting
Main 7. Chek (select). Default option. There is no value in the channel. Waiting
Main 7. Chek (select). Default option. There is no value in the channel. Waiting
Main 7. Chek (select). Default option. There is no value in the channel. Waiting
Main 7. Chek (select). Default option. There is no value in the channel. Waiting
Main 7. Chek (select). Default option. There is no value in the channel. Waiting
Main 7. Chek (select). Default option. There is no value in the channel. Waiting
Main 7. Chek (select). Default option. There is no value in the channel. Waiting
````
`````

Comment: the function `plntsUT` will wait to read from dataEntryChan, and then from channelTJD. Are you writing to those channels?

Comment: "DataEntryChan" and "channelTJD" are return channels from other functions. These two channels are not influencing the problem.
I already tried the PlntsUT() function, and it works correctly. Receive parameters correctly.
I have the problem at the "main" level, with the PositionPlsChan channel. I use this channel to return the map generated in PlntsUT().

Comment: That function is going to block until someone writes to those channels. Your source code does not show if those channels are being written to.

Comment: There is the output of the map after being sent to the return channel (at PlntsUT() level). map[2.4400405e+06:map[0:map[33026:[101.12041750507854 -0.001946848541607366 1.0167564776934892 0.9653730337078059 0.0017513658174335596 -4.0388756783471536e-05]] ]]
I gather from this that the problem is not with the input channels. Otherwise, the function could not have written the map.
Even the return map has been tested. At the end of the PlntsUT(), after receiving the map value, I placed a "select" to verify the status of the channel.

Comment: With that print statement ("value in channel"), you just read the value from the channel. There is nothing in it after you read it.

Comment: I get it. I put the "select" to confirm that ChannelReturn received the map value when I couldn't find a solution to the problem.
Now I have commented (//) that piece of code so that it does not execute.
However, in "main", the return channel that is sent to "PlntsUT ()" (PositionPlsChan) is waiting to receive value.
That is the problem for which I posted the query.

Comment: Add some logging to see if the function is blocked somewhere

Comment: I modified the post. I added detailed output.

Comment: You are assigning the return channel to another channel. The map you sent is stored in the new channel not in the channel main is reading from. Do not do the part where it says "initialize the map".

Comment: That was the problem. I removed that line of code. Now it works. Thank you very much!!! Without people like you, it would be impossible for me to move forward.